# How to select own table name and column names from the SELECT statement itself in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

suppose I have two a table called table1,table2, I'm going to select several specific data from that table.At the same time I want to print the name of the table and columns in the same row.

**table1**

```
------------
ID  |  COL1 
------------ 
1       VAL1
2       VAL2
```

**table2**

```
------------
ID  |  COL2 
------------ 
1       VAL3
2       VAL4
```

suppose I want to get a result as follows

```
------------------------------------
TABLE_NAME | ID  | COL_NAME | VALUE
------------------------------------
table1        1     COL1      VAL1
table1        2     COL1      VAL2
table2        1     COL2      VAL3
table2        2     COL2      VAL4
```

I can do this simply by hard coding table name and column names as follows

```
select 'table1' as TABLE_NAME,ID AS ID,'COL1' AS COL_NAME, COL1 AS VALUE FROM tabl1
union all
select 'table2' as TABLE_NAME,ID AS ID,'COL2' AS COL_NAME, COL2 AS VALUE FROM tabl2;
```

But I want more dynamic way than above method.Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: I suggest you first figure out how to perform a select from a dynamically changing table name (and without using Dynamic SQL!!). Once you figure that out, I suggest you do two things: (1) Share your findings so we all know how to do it, (2) Tackle your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you can get column name but table name you can get using following SQL:

```
select o.object_name,  a.* 
  from <table_name> a
 inner join user_objects o
   on o.object_id = dbms_rowid.rowid_object(a.rowid);
```

Return column name dynamically does not make sense because you always define columns statically in SQL (except * syntax). Unless you want to pivot to key-value pattern.